# add multiple payloads inside for each and provide a final payload which has all payloads

Tags: web-services, foreach, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I am hitting a SOAP web service multiple times inside a For each.In logger I am able to get all the responses one by one, but I want to add all of the responses into a single payload and then send it as payload. can this be done? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution.. Define a variable say `AggregatedPayload` before `for-each` and keep appending `payload` to it

```
<set-variable variableName="aggregatedPayload" value="" />
....

<foreach....>
.....
   <set-variable value="#[aggregatedPayload + payload]" variableName="aggregatedPayload/>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solution works if payload is a string. However since in your case, the payload for each call would be a SOAP response, better create an ArrayList before the loop and insert each response into the list. After the loop you can process the responses in the way you need.

Gijish

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component `scatter-gather` together at component `combine collection`  for management multiple payload. It's very simple and it help you.
For more information show [this article](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/scatter-gather)